# Magento widget error

Tags: magento

I am creating custom widget for my client requirement. I have done all things. and its running fine in back end but when i show it on front end, its show blank page

When i see error log its say

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type:   Vivacity_Sliderwidget_Block_Bestseller' in  /opt/lampp/htdocs/kapil/magentoTesting/magento9/app/Mage.php:595
```

Below is my code

```
app/etc/module/Company_Sliderwidget.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<Company_Sliderwidget>
<active>true</active>
<codePool>community</codePool>
<depends>
 <Mage_Cms />
</depends>
</Company_Sliderwidget>
</modules>
</config>
```

community/Company/Sliderwidget/block/Bestseller.php

```
<?php
class Company_Sliderwidget_Block_Bestseller extends Mage_Core_Block_Template implements Mage_Widget_Block_Interface {
protected function _toHtml() {
$character = "hello";
return $character;
}
}
```

community/Company/Sliderwidget/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<Company_Sliderwidget>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</Company_Sliderwidget>
</modules>
<global>
<blocks>
    <sliderwidget>
            <class>Company_Sliderwidget_Block</class>
    </sliderwidget>
</blocks>
<helpers>
         <sliderwidget>
                <class>Company_Sliderwidget_Helper</class>
            </sliderwidget>
    </helpers>
</global>
</config>
```

community/Company/Sliderwidget/etc/widget.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<widgets>
<sliderwidget_bestseller type="sliderwidget/bestseller">
<name>Product Slider Widget</name>
<description>Display slider option in widgets</description>
</sliderwidget_bestseller>
</widgets>
```

community/Company/Sliderwidget/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
class Company_Sliderwidget_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

Any one can help me to sort out this problem

Comment: Cheers resolved "block" should be "Block"